# Count visible rows from a specific class in html table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

How to count total visible rows from a specific class such as ".CountTwo" in html table using JavaScript, I have a code below that filters table rows while typing.

I'm having issues here

`count.push(document.querySelectorAll('.CountTwo'))`

```js
function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  if (document.getElementById('name').checked) {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("MyTable");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    count = [];
    rowsFound = [];
    // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
      td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; // change number to any other number to target column for table search
      if (td) {
        txtValue = td.textContent || td.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          rowsFound.push(1)
          count.push(document.querySelectorAll('.CountTwo'))
        } else {
          tr[i].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("archieve").innerHTML = count.length;
    document.getElementById("statistic").innerHTML = rowsFound.length;
  }
}
```

```css
#MyTable tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#MyTable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #313131;
}

#MyTable tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E5BB7F;
}

#MyTable a {
  color: rgb(84, 204, 255);
}

#MyTable tbody tr {
  background-color: #0a2c5500;
}
```

```html
<table id="MyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>category</th>
      <th>link</th>
      <th>link2</th>
      <th>link3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1/1/2023</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a class="CountTwo" target="_BLANK" href="#">Link To File</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1/1/2023</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a class="CountTwo" target="_BLANK" href="#">Link To File</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1/1/2023</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a class="CountTwo" target="_BLANK" href="#">Link To File</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the aim of `count.push(document.querySelectorAll('.CountTwo'))` ??

Comment: the aim is to make it count how many .CountTwo classes on the screen while filtering HTML table

Comment: Why don't you just do something like `CountTwoCounter++`in that place then? (Properly initialized with 0 before the whole process, of course.) And if you need to make it dependent on whether the current row actually has that class - check with `tr[i].classList.contains("CountTwo")` first?

Comment: can you demonstrate that?

Comment: done, i have edited the code i also edited javascript code to remove confusion

Comment: how do i send the whole source file?

Comment: See my answer. It should work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added eventListeners and used your HTML

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // when page loads
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput"),
    trs = document.querySelectorAll("#MyTable tbody tr"),
    name = document.getElementById('name');

  function myFunction() {
    let cnt = 0;
    if (name.checked) {
      const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      trs.forEach(tr => {
        const td = tr.querySelectorAll("td")[1];
        const txtValue = td.textContent;
        const hide = filter && txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) === -1;
        tr.hidden = hide;
        if (!hide) cnt++;
      });
    } else {
      trs.forEach(tr => tr.hidden = false);
      cnt = trs.length;
    }
    let visible = [...document.querySelectorAll(".CountTwo")].filter(link => !link.closest('tr').hidden).length;

    document.getElementById("archieve").innerHTML = cnt;
    document.getElementById("statistic").innerHTML = visible;
  }
  input.addEventListener("input", myFunction);
  name.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
  myFunction(); // set the values
})
```

```css
#MyTable tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

#MyTable tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #313131;
}

#MyTable tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E5BB7F;
}

#MyTable a {
  color: rgb(84, 204, 255);
}

#MyTable tbody tr {
  background-color: #0a2c5500;
}
```

```html
Filter <input type="text" id="myInput" /> <label>Name: <input type="checkbox" checked id="name" /></label>
<span id="archieve">0</span>
<span id="statistic">0</span>

<table id="MyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>number</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>category</th>
      <th>link</th>
      <th>link2</th>
      <th>link3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John A</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1/1/2023</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a class="CountTwo" target="_BLANK" href="#">Link To File</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>John B</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1/1/2023</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a class="CountTwo" target="_BLANK" href="#">Link To File</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>JohnC</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1/1/2023</td>
    <td>A</td>
    <td><a class="CountTwo" target="_BLANK" href="#">Link To File</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this works and counts the classes but it doesnt count ONLY VISIBLE classes, it counts visible and not visible while filtering html table

Comment: how do i reflect your code inside my code? because its not working

Comment: Can i add you in discord? im very new here i dont know how to share here it says only comnments

Comment: See my code. I had to make the names different to show it. But there is no difference between visible rows and visible links

Comment: IT WOORKED THANK YOU